# How can I produce TLE output error in VS code editor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am using VS code editor and sometimes when my code enters in Infinite loop it freezes my whole computer and I have to restart the system by pressing power key which is very annoying. I want my code to give TLE verdict if it cross the 1sec time like the online compiler. Is there any way to do it ? I am reading my input from input.txt file and writing all the output to output.txt file. After getting freeze my output.txt file size becomes more than 1 gb which I have to delete manually after restarting.
My setup looks like this

```
void solve(){
   while(true){
     cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
   }

}
int main() {
    FAST
 
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    #endif

    ll t;
    cin >> t;

    while(t--){
        solve();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using chrono time but couldn't able to implement correctely.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? If you freeze the whole machine you've likely run out of memory

Comment: I don't know much about debugging the code using vs tools. Yeah maybe I run out of memory and the one thing which I noticed that my output.txt file size becomes more than 1 gb and then I have to delete it after restarting the system. Could we make any code changes so that it never get into that infinite loop ?

Comment: What OS, windows?

Comment: Yes , I'm using Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You can press ctrl+c in the vscode terminal to terminate execution.

Comment: the whole system gets freezed, so I couldn't be able to give any command; even the Ctrl+ALT+Del command not works.